# How do you call a modal with an anchor tag in bootstrap 5.. I tried using the modal ID in the href as i saw in w3school but nothing happen

Tags: html, python-3.x, anchor, bootstrap5-modal

here is a pic showing my code some assistance is really needed
[pic showing my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5OU3.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [don't upload code, results or data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct, have you linked bootstrap Javascript correctly?

have you tried using `data-bs-target="#sample"` instead of using href? (not sure but it might be changed since V5 has changed data attribute names to data-`bs`-something)

Comment: thanks, I had figured it out after I forgot to link bootstrap JS